# WCF + Enterprise Library + ValidationFault

Tags: wcf, validation, enterprise-library

I am trying to catch the `ValidationFault` exceptions of my service and return a instance of `MyClass` with the property Message filled with the validation error provided by EntLib when my client calls one of my service methods without the correct parameters (I can't use complex types).

I tried to implement two interfaces to accomplish this task: `IParameterInspector` and `IOperationInvoker`. The problem is after the method `BeforeCall` is called (of the `IParameterInspector` interface), EntLib throws the `ValidationFault` exception but I can't catch it and my code doesn't reach the Invoke method of my `IOperationInvoker` class and because of that I can't replace the return value with a instance of `MyClass`.

Remember, my client is not based on .NET platform and there's no such thing as catch(`FaultException<ValidationFault>` ex) there. That's why I MUST work with a default object on my service responses.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use an [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) implementation similar to Enterprise Library's WCF ExceptionShielding?  Basically catch all exceptions and if it's a `FaultException<ValidationFault>` then convert the ValidationFault to your custom message and return it.

It looks like the output of ProvideFault is a Message so you could return a message instead of a fault.  This [posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/961f822b-046b-4119-927c-7b8ed00b6844) seems to give the approach.